# Множество проектов в одном окне idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Интересует возможность работы с множеством проектов из одного окна идеи.Сколько не искал в просторах интернета , всюду твердят что нельзя , где-то приписывают даже к минусам идеи. Всё бы хорошо , но я видел десятки раз , что у людей 2+ проекта в одном окне (не модулями).
[image: 2 проекта]

Всё это надобно , чтоб можно было не переключаясь между окнами собирать проекты и запускать их (на сколько я понимаю модули нельзя собирать,конфигуратора нет).

Как реализовать это?

Comment: Вот кто точно смог бы дать ответ - это эти люди.

Comment: Хоть и не принято тут посылать, но все же на enSO было бы больше шансов узнать ответ на сий вопрос, т.к. там обитают люди с этой компании и дают ответы по вопросам по своим продуктам.. вот эти дяди https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder  |  https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole

Comment: Обновляться пробовал? Вроде в новых версиях видел, при открытии второго проекта в том же окне предлагают добавить дополнительный корень в уже открытый...

Comment: И вот ещё: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40174950/2110496

Answer (score 0):

попробуй скинуть проекты в одну папку и открыть эту папку. Самый легкий способ.